# How to toggle a Key Press

Tags: xna, keyboard, toggle

I have the issue. I have programmed my Shoot em up and i came to dead end when i have to ask so many questions in here

`if(key State.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
      {
         Shoot Bullets();
      }`

Problem is when i Hold Space bar it shoots....i do not want to hold Space bar for 30 minutes just to end the level. I wanna make it to toggle.
What is best and least coded way to do it.
I did spend like 2 days trying to figure this out and i can't...help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @folkol suggested:

Include:

```
bool Shoot;
```

And initialize as:

```
Shoot = false;
```

What you check for input

```
if(key State.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) // Need to flip on key release
    Shoot = !Shoot // Flips the variable
```

And in your **Update()** Method:

```
if(Shoot)
    Shoot Bullets(); // Shoots
```

Notice that this will flip the `Shoot` Variable a lot. You will need to create an `oldState` value and flip on key release.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "Shoot Bullets", flip the value of a boolean variable. And use that variable as the indicated for whether you should fire some bullets in any given game loop iteration.

Something like this:

```
public class MyGame : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    /* Some other state */
    bool isShooting = false;

    /* Some other methods */
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        /* Some other code */
        if(keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            // Flip the boolean value. If it was failse, set it to and vice versa
            isShooting = !isShooting; true.
        }

        if(isShooting)
        {
            Shoot.Bullets();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not have boolean variable. And what to flip?

Comment: I meant that instead of checking for keydown about your shooting, you should check the value of a boolean variable and shoot if it is true (You have to create this variable yourself, outside the game loop), and then in your if-block above, flip the value of that boolean variable. Like myVariable = !myVariable.

Comment: No, sorry. I do not even recognize what language you are using.

Comment: C# that is what i am using as Programming language

Comment: It did not look like C# with those spaces and such, but I have updated this answer with an example. There are some issues with a naïve solution like this, it will rapidly toggle the "isShooting"-state if you hold the button and such, but I leave that up to you as an exercise. You could be able to sort that out with the help of Goolgle. As a hint; You should only flip the state if the key state was changed since last update.

Answer (score 0):

I added another short but correct example for you, some of the other answers were pretty much there, but had some errors in them.

```
    KeyboardState kbState;
    bool isShooting;

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {     
        KeyboardState lastkbState = kbState;
        kbState = Keyboard.GetState();

        if (kbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && lastkbState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
        {
            isShooting = !isShooting;
        }

        if (isShooting)
        {
            Shoot.Bullets();
        }
    }
```

Your other answer I don't have the reptuation to add a comment on doesn't work because you made the previous and the current keyboard state properties equal the same thing.